# Set Values to Input Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a form in which there are several Input element. From A drop down i select value then i need to set the values for each input element for example ;- 1, 2, 3 .
I can do for one input element (each input has same id) but not for all.

Comment: each input element should have a different "id". Please, first change the way using are "id".

Answer (score 0):

You can add to every input a class instead of the id and then use the vanilla JS `getElementsByClassName()`. You'll get an array-like of the required elements which you'll be able to loop through.

It will look something like that:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputClass');

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  ..Your code to manipulate the inputs
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but its setting the value for first input text only not for all

Comment: Take a look at the this jsbin example:
https://jsbin.com/merufedoxa/edit?html,js,output